# What are some of the main ideas in the Grand Prix attack?

Tags: opening, strategy, sicilian-defense

I was looking at ways to improve my game by making it more sharp and be able to attack the kingside as quickly as possible, and I found a move that looks interesting called the [Grand Prix Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Prix_Attack#Grand_Prix_Attack) in Sicilian.

From what I've seen it looks something like this:

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 c5 2. f4
```

But I wanted to get some feedback of people who actually used it, to me it seems the Black can easily get around it by playing `...e6` and `...d5`, right?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct in that Black's goal is to play `...e6` and `...d5`, especially if White has played `Bc4`.

Some players will only play into the Grand Prix if Black has committed to an early `...d6`, in that case, Black loses a tempo if he then plays for `...e6` and `...d5`.

Answer (score 6):

The point of the Grand Prix attack is that white either attacks the kingside with `f5` or cramps black in the center with `e5`.  There are a lot of dangerous lines, but it is true that it's generally not played very often today.  In particular, the Tal Gambit has come to defuse it, leading many white players to start with `2. Nc3` followed by `3. f4`.